# Proof using Weierstrass theorem (Extreme value theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

How do we approach something like this:

- Show that the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2 + x^4 + x^6}$ has a maximum $M = max f(\mathbb{R})$.

I understand the concept of extreme value theorem, but in our course we have totally different approach in showing these. Using the Weierstrass theorem you don't have to compute any derivatives in order to show that the function attains a maximum. Could someone explain how this works and how do we show this mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$. Now, $f(1)=\frac{1}{4}>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$, there is $N>1$ such that if $|x|>N$, then $|f(x)|<1/4$. Therefore, all values of $f(x)$ outside the interval $[-N,N]$ are smaller than $1/4$. Since $f(1)=1/4$, then, if there is a maximum it is not going to be outside $[-N,N]$.

Now, the interval $[-N,N]$ is closed and bounded (it is compact). The function $f$ is continuous, since it is a quotient of the continuous function $x$ and the continuous function $2+x^2+x^4$ and the latter doesn't vanish on $\mathbb{R}$.

By Weierstrass theorem, $f(x)$ attains a maximum on $[-N,N]$. This maximum must be greater than $1/4=f(1)$, since $x=1\in[-N,N]$. Therefore, this maximum is also a maximum on all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: " Since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$, there is $N>1$ such that if $|x|>N$, then $|f(x)|<1/4$. " This is the part bit confusing to me, I understand that this is due to the definition of limits, but still cannot quite understand it.

Comment: Aha perhaps i understood by looking at the graph of the function. Since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$ we could have picked an arbitrary point $x$ and then pick $N$ to be greater than that so the inequality would hold?

Comment: @Daniel The definition of limit, used with $\epsilon=1/4$ gives you the existence of an $N_0>0$ such that the rest works. Any larger $N>N_0$ also would work, so we pick one that is both $N>N_0$ and $N>1$. the latter such that $x=1\in[-N,N]$.